# Alignment of enumerate (numbered by subsection) and the existing text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate

I have a document full of lists which I need to refer to later in the document. Therefore I number my lists (`enumerate`) by subsections. I have chosen to specify this globally by this line in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand*{\theenumi}{\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}}
```

This gives me the result I want, but because each item now consists of 4 digits (chapter.section.subsection.item), some of the numbers end up in the left margin:

[image: Misalignment of enumerate and chapter/section/subsection numbers and text.]

I would like the numbers of enumerate to (left) align with the rest of the document text (including subsection numbers as seen in the picture above). How is this done globally, since I have a massive amount of lists?

If relevant: I am using `memoir`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to Harish's answer, but there's no need for

```
\renewcommand*{\theenumi}{\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}}
```

You can simply define

```
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*,align=left,label=\thesubsection.\arabic*.}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*,align=left,label=\thesubsection.\arabic*.}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item aaa
  \item bbb
  \item ccc
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need it only for a few `enumerate` environments, instead of setting globally

```
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*,align=left,label=\thesubsection.\arabic*.}
```

use these settings locally by issuing

```
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,align=left,label=\thesubsection.\arabic*.]
```

Note that you may need to load `enumitem` with the `shortlabels` option

```
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
```

if you have already customized `enumerate` lists.

Comment: This seems to work, although I get several errors from other numbered lists where I don't want the chapter.section.subsection.item style. In this case I have used: `\begin{enumerate}[1]` to make a list with _only_ one number (no reference needed). How do I implement "your" code while still being able to use the simpler version of numbered list?

Comment: I have several lists (as in way too many, but all necessary), some of which need to be numbered by subsection numbering and some which need to be numbered 1. item, 2. item, etc. I think the subsection numbering works smoothly, but the simpler versions result in errors. How do I make these simpler numbered lists locally, while still globally defining the subsection numbered lists? (Is my point clear?)

Comment: @Thomas See the edit. Using `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` should solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct and it works perfectly. I saw another of your edits right before my previous comment. This really works, I can't believe it! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `enumitem` and its `align=left`

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\renewcommand*{\theenumi}{\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A sub section}
\begin{enumerate}[align=left,leftmargin=*]
  \item Some item Some item Some item Some item Some item Some item Some item Some item Some item Some item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
\end{enumerate}
Some text here
\end{document}
```

Remember that `memoir` class emulates the functions of only `enumerate` package and for more control, `enumitem` is recommended. Here is an example of more control with a customized alignment.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem} % for \midrule macro
\renewcommand*{\theenumi}{\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}}
\SetLabelAlign{myleft}{\strut\smash{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\raggedright#1}}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A sub section}
\begin{enumerate}[align=myleft,labelwidth=1.25cm,leftmargin=\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep,
        itemindent=!]
  \item Some item Some item Some item Some item Some item Some item Some item Some item Some item Some item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
  \item Some item
\end{enumerate}
Some text here
\end{document}
```

[image]