# Enumitem/Enumerate Margins in Section vs. Subsection

Tags: sectioning, enumerate, enumitem

I am writing a contract wherein I separate the different provisions with numbered items (following [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227005/alignment-of-enumerate-numbered-by-subsection-and-the-existing-text)), as in the MWE below.  The margins in the `enumerate` lists in the Subsections display correctly with the text block aligned with the Section and Subsection headers.  However, when I add a list below just a Section, the margin alignment is off.

How can I get the list below the Section to align at a 0.5in margin like the other list?

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=1.25in,left=1in,right=1in,bottom=1.25in,showframe=false,headheight=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%----Change default LaTeX section styles---------------------------
\usepackage{titlesec} % Lets user adjust section header formatting
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\llap{\makebox[0in][l]{\thesection.}}}{0.5in}{\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\llap{\parbox{0in}{\thesubsection}}}{0.5in}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont}{\llap{\parbox{0in}{\thesubsubsection}}}{0.5in}{}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*,align=left,label=\thesubsection.\arabic*.}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=0.5in}

\begin{document}
    
\section{First Section}

\subsection{First Subsection}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[1]

    \item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

\section{Second Section}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\thesection.\arabic*.]
    \item \lipsum[3]
    
    \item \lipsum[4]
\end{enumerate}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: unaligned lists]

Comment: `leftmargin=*` says you want `enumitem` to figure out an appropriate margin. Since the labels are narrower for sections than subsections, the margin turns out smaller. To ensure the same margin specify a static value for `leftmargin` e.g. `leftmargin=12.5mm` or whatever.

Comment: @cfr, this does align the text block margin, but it pulls the paragraph numbers to the right.  How can I keep the number anchored on the left?

Comment: `\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=0.5in,labelwidth=0.5in,align=left,itemindent=0pt,labelsep=*,label=\thesubsection.\arabic*.}`?

Comment: @cfr `labelwidth` is what I was missing.  Thanks!  If you want to quickly add this as the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Not entirely sure it is answer-worthy, but the site prefers tidiness. Incidentally, I find page 3 of the documentation invaluable in such cases ;). (A picture is worth a thousand words ....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=0.5in,labelwidth=0.5in,align=left,itemindent=0pt,labelsep=*,label=\thesubsection.\arabic*.}
```

produces the desired result

[image: aligned margins]